# How to use Metrics in Stagemonitor

Tags: java, performance, stagemonitor

I am using stagemonitor for get metrics for different methods. I'm using PetClinic application locally for get a idea and using browser-widget for testing.I find that we can track metrics using @Timed , @Metered annotations. Is it possible to use them in the petclinic application and view them from browser-widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is currently not possible. However, stagemonitor offers a "Custom Metrics" dashboard for Grafana.

To see the metrics locally, currently the only way is to enable periodic logging of all metrics.